# Full screen interfaces in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, performance, user-interface, fullscreen, windows-forms-designer

I am fairly new to C# I have just completed a unit at uni on it. They did not focus on anything to do with full screen applications. I have found out how to create a full screen app. I was just wondering how I would create and move between different UIs while in full screen. In our unit we just created whole new windows and I don't think that that would be very efficient.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a lot of new windows is indeed an uncommon practice these days.
Instead, an application creates a single window and lays out User Controls within that window.

Each user control groups together a subset of user interactions that correlate to one another.

[This tutorial should get you started on Winforms User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

I must, however, reccomend that you do not pursue practicing Winforms, as it is dated as a framework, and moreover- the programming model it forces on applications is not ideal for today's needs.

I therefore suggest you start with at least WPF (or UWP)- this will ensure that you put effort into something more worthwhile, carrer wise.